# dimension of a subvector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$ , $\dim V=n$ and $W$ be a subspace of $V$ , $\dim W=m<n$. We set $E=\{T:V\to V: T ~\text{restrict to}~ W ~\text{is zero}\}$. What is $\dim E$ as a subspace of $L(V,V)$.

**Background:**

$L(V,V)$= set of all linear transformations from $V$ to $V$.

Comment: What is $T\mbox{ over }W$? what is $L(V,V)$?

Comment: By "$T$ over $W$ is zero", do you mean that $W$ lies in the kernel of $T$, or do you want the kernel to precisely be $W$?

Comment: Ah, so you mean $T(W)=0$, or rather $W\subset\ker T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think with matrix: $E$ is the set of $(n,n)$ matrix which have $m$ colums 0, and the rest what you want... So dim$E=n(n-m)$

Answer (score 1):

Let the basis of $W$ be $\{e_1,\dots, e_m\}$ and the basis of $V$ be $\{e_1,\dots,e_m,\dots,e_n\}$. Any $T\in E$ has the following representation
$$T(x)=x_{m+1}e_{m+1}+\dots+x_ne_n,$$
where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.